# "flowing" speed of an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, speed-of-light

Consider a capacitor made of two infinite plates which are at a very large distance $d$ from each other.

We place a positive charge on a plate and a negative one on the other one. Two electrical fields then start propagating at speed $c$, and after a time $d/c$, their superposition results in a homogeneous field $\vec{E}$ everywhere between the plates (if this is not the case, then please correct me and ignore the remaining of the question).

Now if I'm somewhere between theses two plates, is it possible to distinguish between the 3 different situations:
a) I'm static with respect to the plates
b) I'm moving (at constant speed) towards one of the plate (in the direction of $\vec{E}$)
c) I'm moving alongside the plates (perpendicular to the $\vec{E}$)

Is it possible, without looking at the plates (say there are too far apart), but by looking only a the field $\vec{E}$, to determine in which situation I am ?

Is there a thing such as a "flowing speed" of an electric field ? (beside the "propagation speed", which I understand to be $c$)

Comment: A start for you could be to look up the differences for static fields and radiation fields, they're not the same. I'd argue that the static fields to not propagate, they're a potential and thus they're always there, but i might be wrong, i'd like someone elses input on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electromagnetic field is not the same in different inertial frames. The parallel and perpendicular components (parallel or penpendicular to the direction of motion) of the electric and magnetic fields transform according to Joules-Bernoulli equation:

$$
  \mathbf{E_\parallel}' = \mathbf{E_\parallel} \\
  \mathbf{B_\parallel}' = \mathbf{B_\parallel} \\
       \mathbf{E_\bot}' = \gamma \left( \mathbf{E}_\bot + \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B} \right) \\
       \mathbf{B_\bot}' = \gamma \left( \mathbf{B}_\bot - \frac{1}{c^2} \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{E} \right) 
$$

where

$$\gamma = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}}$$

You could measure the electric and the magnetic field along the parallel and perpendicular direction in order to deduce in which direction you are moving. You will also obtain the velocity of your inertial frame.

a) In this case, you are in the same inertial frame as the plates, so $\mathbf{E}' = \mathbf{E}$.

b) Since you are moving along the direction of the electric field, $\mathbf{E}_\bot=0$ and $\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{E}=0$. You will measure no magnetic field, and the electric field in yout inertial frame will also be $E_\parallel=E$. This situation can not be distinguished from the previous one.

c) In this case, you are moving perpendicular to the direction of the electric field, so $\mathbf{E}_\parallel=0$. The perpendicular components of the fields will be $\mathbf{E_\bot}' = \gamma \mathbf{E}_\bot$ and $\mathbf{B_\bot}' = - \gamma \frac{1}{c^2} \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{E}$. Therefore, you can deduce the direction of motion and the velocity at which you are moving.